# changing button style not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the full calendar. I want to change the default, hover or active state for buttons on the header.

All I want it to make :

```
default: black background, white text color  
hover :  red background color,  white text color  
active:  green background color,  white text color
```

The CSS code:

```
.fc-state-default {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.fc-state-active {
  background-color: green;
}

.fc-state-hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: medium;
}
```

For some reasons that I can't understand I can't change the style of those buttons.

Here is a js fiddle. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e3brb5mq/#&togetherjs=xwRcFsLASg)

Please, can somebody help me!

EDIT if I have something like this:

```
<div class="fc-right">
<div class="fc-button-group">
<button type="button" class="fc-month-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-left fc-state-active">month</button>
<button type="button" class="fc-agendaWeek-button fc-button fc-state-default">week</button>
<button type="button" class="fc-agendaDay-button fc-button fc-state-default">day</button>
<button type="button" class="fc-today-button fc-button fc-state-default fc-corner-right fc-state-disabled" disabled="disabled">today</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

It is quite simple, just add these css classes:

```
.fc-button .fc-button-inner:hover {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}

.fc-button.fc-state-active .fc-button-inner {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
}

.fc-button .fc-button-inner {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/e3brb5mq/2/)

Comment: thank you for your, I edited my question, please can you check what should I do in that different situation?

Comment: Fiddle link in the post does not seems to be working. I update it http://jsfiddle.net/0gdL6bfy/5/